# can't reshape to wide with reshape()

Tags: r, reshape

I am trying to code the same operation using reshape() and spread() and dcast(), but am getting stuck on the basic reshape.

This is the head of the data, but it gives the same error on the 1st 12 rows as it does on whole df where there are 82 ID's (246 rows).

```
head(alcL, n=12)
   ID COA MALE AGE_14   ALCUSE      PEER
1   1   1    0      0 1.732051 1.2649111
2   1   1    0      1 2.000000 1.2649111
3   1   1    0      2 2.000000 1.2649111
4   2   1    1      0 0.000000 0.8944272
5   2   1    1      1 0.000000 0.8944272
6   2   1    1      2 1.000000 0.8944272
7   3   1    1      0 1.000000 0.8944272
8   3   1    1      1 2.000000 0.8944272
9   3   1    1      2 3.316625 0.8944272
10  4   1    1      0 0.000000 1.7888544
11  4   1    1      1 2.000000 1.7888544
12  4   1    1      2 1.732051 1.7888544

       ID            COA              MALE            AGE_14      ALCUSE           PEER       
 Min.   : 1.0   Min.   :0.0000   Min.   :0.0000   Min.   :0   Min.   :0.000   Min.   :0.0000  
 1st Qu.:21.0   1st Qu.:0.0000   1st Qu.:0.0000   1st Qu.:0   1st Qu.:0.000   1st Qu.:0.0000  
 Median :41.5   Median :0.0000   Median :1.0000   Median :1   Median :1.000   Median :0.8944  
 Mean   :41.5   Mean   :0.4512   Mean   :0.5122   Mean   :1   Mean   :0.922   Mean   :1.0176  
 3rd Qu.:62.0   3rd Qu.:1.0000   3rd Qu.:1.0000   3rd Qu.:2   3rd Qu.:1.732   3rd Qu.:1.5492  
 Max.   :82.0   Max.   :1.0000   Max.   :1.0000   Max.   :2   Max.   :3.606   Max.   :2.5298  


alcW <- alcL %>%
  reshape(data =alcL, 
  direction    ="wide",
  timevar      ="AGE_14",
  idvar        ="ID",
  v.names      =c("ALCUSE","PEER")

Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, , varying[, i], value = c(1.73205077648163,  : 
  duplicate subscripts for columns
```

I tried some variations where I used actual age (14,15,16) and got messages about holes in new columns.

Using AGE_14, which is 0,1,2, I can't get past the duplicate subscript error

I confirm there are no NA values in the timeVar. Nobody has a duplicate subscript:

```
AGE_14   0   1   2   3   4 Sum
   0    51  16   9   6   0  82
   1    36  25  14   5   2  82
   2    33  18  17  14   0  82
   Sum 120  59  40  25   2 246
```

I tried to specify the varying, although I expected it to be created. I got error about incorrect number of dimensions.

```
alcW <- alcL %>%
  reshape(data =alcL, 
  direction    ="wide",
  timevar      ="AGE_14",
  idvar        ="ID",
  v.names      =c("ALCUSE","PEER"),
  varying      =c(paste0("alc",1:3),paste0("peer",1:3)) )
```

Comment: ok, varying has to be a list, with an element for each v.name and each element a set of wide names

Answer (score 0):

ok, varying has to be a list, with an element for each v.name and each element a set of wide names

```
alcW <- alcL %>%
  reshape(data =alcL, 
  direction    ="wide",
  timevar      ="AGE_14",
  idvar        ="ID",
  v.names      =c("ALCUSE","PEER"),
  varying      =list(paste0("alc",1:3),paste0("peer",1:3)))
```